How can I publish my alternate sphere rules for Mage?
I have been designing alternative rules for Mage: The Ascension. (My alternate magic rules are published on the V5 Homebrew Wiki.) I want to find a way of publishing them, without infringing on the already existing copyrights of this very popular RPG. Paradox Interactive currently owns White Wolf games and has a "Dark Pack Agreement". The agreement allows fans to make their own characters sheets and fan fiction. But I don't fully understand the agreement.

What part of the agreement is giving you trouble? By the first use of the word publish, I'm assuming you mean sell?

Follow their guidance and ask on their Creators Discord or social media
The Dark Pack Agreement only allows you to share if you are not making money from your content

You can create and share the following non-monetized and non-commercial content:

So if by "publish" you mean to charge for your alternate rule (for example on a site like DriveThruRPG), that is very clearly not allowed under this license.
If by "publish" you just mean to make your content freely available, its less clear. The above intro is followed by a bullet list of things that are allowed, and that list does not include alternate rules systems. (The closest is a reference to another agreement about game mods, but as far as I can tell, that one is about computer games that you access through Paradox's services).
The agreement then says

If the kind of content you want to make and share isn’t listed above please feel free to contact us and ask about it through our social media or Creators Discord.

So I’d recommend you do that.

Storyteller's Vault should be your next stop.
The Dark Pack license is for material that's not meant to be sold or distributed for gain. If what you want is to publish your material, the information and licensing you'll need is found on the Storyteller's Vault. The STV license lets you use World of Darkness trademarks and sell on their creator content site in exchange for a cut of the money. The material you've shown would be in line with what's available there. Here's a place to get started.

STV applies a different license pack than the Dark Pack Agreement. You might elaborate on that.
